# What is meant by EFD core?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, magnetics

What does EFD stand for in an EFD30 core size?

[Reference](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/80/db/fer/efd_30_15_9.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Not an answer but E is the general shape (the letter capital E if you stand it on its side) and I’d guess they just added letters from there as they iterated on it.

Comment: my guess is `E` core for `F`lat transformer design in `D`C/DC converters`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [datasheet](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/download/531522/449506bb84194c3510018ae82f66b4cc/pdf-ecores.pdf), general information about cores.

> 

a) Types with round center leg
We offer the following types:
■ ER cores
■ EQ cores
■ **ETD** cores to IEC 62317-6 (**Economic Transformer Design**)
E cores with round center leg offer the advantage of easy winding, particularly when thick winding
wires are used, compact mounting dimensions and wide openings on each side. ETD cores have
the additional benefit of an almost constant cross section along the magnetic path. A wide variety
of optimized accessories is available. ER cores in sizes 9.5 and 11/5 are particularly suitable for
designing transformers with low overall height and high inductance. They come in material T38 for
broadband applications plus in N87, N97, N88, N95, N96, N92 and N49 for power transformers for
frequencies up to and over 500 kHz (PC200 up to 4 MHz).

b) Types with rectangular center leg
■ E cores
■ **EFD** cores (**Economic Flat Transformer Design**);
EV cores
The conventional E cores with rectangular center leg are available in a wide variety of sizes.
EFD cores have an optimized cross section and enable the design of very flat and compacts transformers, even for high-frequency applications.

c) **ELP** cores (**E Low Profile**)
ELP cores enable the design of very flat transformers and feature excellent thermal performance
due to the large core surface. ELP cores are now specified in IEC 62317-9

Comment: "EFD cores have an optimized cross section and enable the design of very flat and compacts transformers, even for high-frequency applications."
- Why did they mention-  "even" for high frequency applications. 
High frequency transformers are by default compact, right?

Comment: Ok for "even". Note that these chokes are used only at some hundred of kHz ... but until powers of 10 kW ... (intro section 2).